# How to avoid plain-text passwords when configuring Corda Enterprise?

Tags: enterprise, corda

I'm working in a setting where storing plain-text passwords is not acceptable, neither in files nor in databases. The Corda Enterprise guide, section 7.6.3 on RPC security, states that passwords can be encrypted using Apache Shiro, by setting `passwordEncryption = SHIRO_1_CRYPT`. Is this setting applied to all passwords in `node.conf`, or just to the RPC passwords? If it applies only to RPC passwords, how can other passwords be secured? Other types of passwords include DBMS and keystore passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identified that you need the following setting in your node configuration.

```
passwordEncryption = SHIRO_1_CRYPT
```

Take a look at this page, it outlines how to specify security configuration for your node password. You simply specify it for each node and then you should be all set.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/operating/clientrpc.html#password-encryption